# shift array elements to associate dates in php

Tags: php, arrays, date, foreach

I'm having a multidimensional array of orders and users. This array loops through orders in the last 4 days and displays date and total from the database. But as you see if the user has no sales in the database in a specific day the array just loops through these sales and table is not complete. What I want is to **echo '0'** in the day that has **no sales** and echo the correct date and total in the correct column

```
foreach ($orders[$x] as $order) {
   echo $order->order_date.'->'.$order->total
}
```

(First row is the header)

```
25-10-2016       26-10-2016        27-10-2016        28-10-2016        29-10-2016

25-10-2016->100  26-10-2016->50    27-10-2016->30    28-10-2016->100   29-10-2016->150
25-10-2016->100  27-10-2016->30    28-10-2016->100   29-10-2016->150
26-10-2016->50   27-10-2016->30
```

The desired format:(First row is the header)

```
25-10-2016       26-10-2016        27-10-2016        28-10-2016        29-10-2016

25-10-2016->100  26-10-2016->50    27-10-2016->30    28-10-2016->100   29-10-2016->150
25-10-2016->100       0            27-10-2016->30    28-10-2016->100   29-10-2016->150
     0           26-10-2016->50    27-10-2016->30         0
```

Comment: Just check if total is null and then print 0 if soo

Comment: let's say that the array has only 3 elements only there'r no null dates nor total but I want to echo '0' in the correct column that it's date isn't in the array

Comment: And what is wrong with I said? If you have no sales what value is saved in the table of your database? I guess that even if you no have sales the date of the day is still saved, right?

Comment: The query fetches the last 5 days and returns an array of existing sales doesn't matter if they are 1 or 4 it'll just return sales it finds so if a day has no sales it won't even exist in the array and the array will contain only 4 sales with total and date. the that has no sales won't be returned at all because it doesn't exist

Comment: And the dates you want to check if exists in the array where they come from?

Comment: the array contains a date range of sales in the last 5 days and any day with no sales is not inserted in the array because it's not in the query result so an array may contain 5 days and another array may contain just 1 day. But all sales will be between today and 4 days before that's the range of dates